# Path monotonic with respect to distance

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, geodesic

I am not really familiar with the subject of geodesics, but I was wondering whether there is a notion of a continuous distance monotonic path, which is slightly more general than geodesics? Specifically, I was thinking that a continuous path $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$ from $x$ to $y$, in a path connected metric space $X$, if

- $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$.
- Every $t_1\leq t_2$ satisfy $d\big(y,\gamma(t_2) \big) \leq d\big(y,\gamma(t_1) \big)$.

The only relevant thing I found was geodesics, but it seems there that they demand roughhly preserving the distance up to a constant. I am demanding less in some sense, and I assumed that someone had already dealt with this definition before in a name I don't know how to search for.
I was also wondering whether perhaps, in a path connected locally compact, this notion coincides with the notion of geodesics?

Answer (score 1):

I have never encountered such a definition, and what I can tell is that there are examples of such paths that are not geodesics.

For instance, consider $\Bbb R ^2$ with its usual euclidean metric, whose geodesics are straight lines. The path $\gamma(t) = \left(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t),\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t)\right)$ from $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ is not a geodesic (it is a circular arc), but
$$
d\left(\gamma(1),\gamma(t)\right)^2 = \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}t)^2+ (1-\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t))^2 = 2(1 - \sin(\frac{\pi}{2}t))
$$
which you can check is decreasing on $[0,1]$, and so is $d\left(\gamma(1),\gamma(t)\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So what you're saying is that this notion is not covered by the notion  of geodesics. Do you know whether geodesics should satisfy this property? Even if geodesics in nice vector spaces?

Comment: geodesics always satisfy (up to a rescaling) $d(\gamma(t),\gamma(1)) = 1-t$ for $t$ close enough to $1$